# Producer-consumer with interval partitioning

Tags: java, concurrency, partitioning, producer-consumer, java-threads

I have an interesting producer-consumer spin-off to implement and I cannot wrap my head around its algorithm. So, every **producer** will "produce" numbers between the given range (min, max) which give the same reminder to the division by the given "quotient". Same goes for the **consumer**.

Extra requirement: finite buffer.

**My thoughts on this:**

- a coarse-grained queue which uses a lock and two conditions for push and pop, alongside a number of expected parties and arrived parties, used to determine of the queue is still available for the consumers. (one considers that a queue is available if there are still items in it or there are active writers (arrived != expected))
- a  "Producer class" which contains minimum, maximum, a quotient and the shared queue as fields and has a method which produces and returns values based on the given fields.
- a "Consumer" class which contains the same fields as the "Producer" class and has the method "consume" which pops an item from the queue and "consumes" (prints it out) it. A consumer will consume as long as the queue is available.

**My problems:**

- How would one ensure that all numbers between a given workload interval (start, end) would be produced and consumed by x producers and y consumers (x != y) ?
- How would one implement the consume mechanism ?
- How would one perform the partitioning of values of producers and consumers so all the values of workload interval are used?

I was thinking about using an array list for the "buffer" and every consumer would perform a lock-free lookup for a "compatible" element to consume, removing an element if one available or trying again if none available. I think this would be inefficient because of wasted CPU cycles on "tries".

**PS**: I am using java for this, but pseudo-code is really good as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be sure that producer produces all numbers from given range that have the same remainder you can use the following pseudo-code

```
int current = start;
while (current++ <= end) { //assuming your ranges are inclusive
  if (current % quotient == 0) {
    publish(current);
  }
}
```

To support partitioning you basically need some kind of `Map<YourKey, Queue>`. Each producer and consumer will be associated with a key and producer will publish to the queue associated with his key and consumer will consume from a queue associated with its key. You can use your range as a key for a queue.

Comment: This would be a great idea, unfortunately, I am allowed to use at most 1 buffer.

Comment: The only requirement I see is **Extra requirement: finite buffer.**. Technically you may have several buffers with cumulative size not exceeding predefined value.

Comment: So you are suggesting that I might be able to split the single bigger buffer into multiple smaller buffers. That might actually work. But how to I share the buffers for, let's say, 555 consumers and 1996 producers ?